# Webpack file-loader and images in CSS

Tags: css, image, webpack, urlloader, webpack-file-loader

I'm using images in my stylesheet (less) fine by doing:

```
.foo { background: url('../images/foo.png') }
```

When using HMR they're base64 encoded into the stylesheet which I'm fine about. However when compiling for production I want the images not to be embedded in the stylesheet. I've tried both [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) and [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader).

With url-loader I couldn't get it to emit the images properly. If I set no limit then the files were emitted to `output/images/` and had the right size but weren't valid images. If I set the limit to something smaller than 8k the images were emitted to `output` and correct.

In either case the emitted images appeared in the CSS like so (example when using url-loader with `limit=1`):

`url(data:image/png;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJhMDdjZWVkMGRiZTNlMjk5ODY5NWQ3ZjM4MzYxZDY1Zi5wbmciOw==);`

Which when you decode it is:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "a07ceed0dbe3e2998695d7f38361d65f.png";
```

How do I get the css to use the URL rather than trying to base64 encode the value?

This is my webpack (still on webpack 1) loaders config:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
},
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css!postcss'),
},
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css!less!postcss'),
},
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
}
```

**Update:** Turns out disabling the [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) stops the URLs from being encoded when using the url-loader (but the images are still not valid) but not when using the file-loader.

**Update 2:** Added a custom loader at the end of the `css!less!postcss` loaders and the source still has the image URL of `../images/foo.png` so it appears the issue is further down the line. Also tried removing the `ExtractTextPlugin` but the compiled JS for the image then has the Base64 encoded value for the export like the CSS does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that having the 2 ExtractTextPlugins (for the `css` & `less` tests were causing the problems) as I don't have any css files I removed the first and it's now working as expected.